# Marginsplot how to remove certain data from graph

Tags: graph, stata

I have a margins plot in Stata with too many lines on it to read the graph well. I want to remove the data that is not the focus of my plot.

For example, the output I have is this `marginsplot` with five lines, each representing a racial group:

[image]

However, I'd only like to display two lines, representing two racial groups (URM and White, Domestic)

Right now my code is:

```
reg y x##i.race $controls
margins x, by (race)
marginsplot
```

Comment: providing example data would improve this question, but I've provided an example below

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by selecting the races for which you calculate the margins:

```
webuse nhanes2, clear
local cntrls "finalwgt iron"
reg bpsystol sex#race `cntrls'
margins sex if inlist(race,1,2)==1, by (race)
marginsplot
```

`coefplot`'s `drop()` option could provide an alternative allows this. Note: `coefplot` is from SSC: `ssc install coefplot`.

Comment: There was a full write-up of `coefplot` at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0059  The code on SSC is more up-to-date.